# R dplyr Replace unique values from one data frame with unique values from other data frame with unequal row numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to replace the unique ID's in one df with the unique ID's from another df.
Let's say df_long contains time series data per trial and df_short only the average values over time.

1. How can I mutate the values in ID if I have to use ID for my grouping in group_by?
2. How do I apply a list of unique values from unique(df_long$ID) to  unique(df_short$ID)
   if the data frames have unequal row numbers?

How would you do this using dplyr?

```
#let's assume this df contains averaged trials 
df_short <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:4,each=9), 
                 Trial= rep(1:3,12),  
                 Session = rep(rep(1:3,each=3),4) ) 

df_long <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(11,13,18,19),each=3*3*3), 
                 Trial= rep(rep(c(1,2,3),each=3),4*3),  
                 Time = rep(1:3,3*4*3),
                 Session = rep(rep(1:3,each=9),4))    

    df_short[1:15,]
       ID Trial Session
    1   1     1       1
    2   1     2       1
    3   1     3       1
    4   1     1       2
    5   1     2       2
    6   1     3       2
    7   1     1       3
    8   1     2       3
    9   1     3       3
    10  2     1       1
    11  2     2       1
    12  2     3       1
    13  2     1       2
    14  2     2       2
    15  2     3       2

df_long[1:15,]
   ID Trial Time Session
1  11     1    1       1
2  11     1    2       1
3  11     1    3       1
4  11     2    1       1
5  11     2    2       1
6  11     2    3       1
7  11     3    1       1
8  11     3    2       1
9  11     3    3       1
10 11     1    1       2
11 11     1    2       2
12 11     1    3       2
13 11     2    1       2
14 11     2    2       2
15 11     2    3       2
```

Result

```
 ID Trial Session
1  11     1       1
2  11     2       1
3  11     3       1
4  11     1       2
5  11     2       2
6  11     3       2
7  11     1       3
8  11     2       3
9  11     3       3
10 13     1       1
11 13     2       1
12 13     3       1
13 13     1       2
14 13     2       2
15 13     3       2
```

Comment: How do you know which IDs to replace? That is, why does `df_short$ID` value `1` become `11`, not `13`? Is it based on the order they first appear?

Comment: @GregorThomas The ID numbers are arbitrary in this case but there are 4 in each data frame. I want to replace 1:4 with  11,13,18,19 respectively. The df_long has more than just the value of 11 in the ID col if you run the code. I just  printed the first 15 rows because it get's very long.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you had shared a complete example and only printed part of it.

Comment: My main question is about the logic. In your comment, you say "respectively", which makes me think it is indeed based on the order - the first ID in `df_short` is 1, and the first ID in `df_long` is 11, therefore 1 is replaced by 11, and so on. Is this the correct logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the replacement is to be done "respectively" (in order of occurrence), here are two options. In both cases I will create a new column so that the result can be verified--I'll leave dropping the old column and renaming the new column up to you.

```
# Option 1: with factor conversion
df_short %>%
  mutate(
    new_ID = factor(ID, levels = unique(ID), labels = unique(df_long$ID)),
    new_ID = as.numeric(as.character(new_ID)) # convert to numeric
)

# Option 2: make a look-up table and join
id_lookup = tibble(ID = unique(df_short$ID), new_ID = unique(df_long$ID))
df_short %>% left_join(id_lookup, by = "ID")
```

If your data is grouped by the ID column, before doing these operations yo ushould `ungroup()`, apply these functions, and `group_by()` again, if necessary. (The join will work fine with grouped data, but you won't be able to drop the old ID column if the data is grouped.)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Your code worked like a charm. Thank you!